# Hadoop not listing any slaves

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, slave

I've followed [this guide](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2015/03/09/install-a-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/) to setup a simple cluster for Hadoop.

Though I can't see my slave node at `http://master:50070`.

I have followed the guide until **Start the Yarn MapReduce Job tracker** and everything is listed as it should when running `jps` on both master and slave node.

In the `hadoop-hadoopuser-datanode-slave-1.log` I see these messages over and over.

```
2016-05-25 13:26:11,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-05-25 13:26:11,886 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2016-05-25 13:26:13,028 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:14,029 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:15,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:16,032 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:17,033 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:18,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:19,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:20,036 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:21,037 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:22,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-05-25 13:26:22,040 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: master/10.0.1.32:54310
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by removing the line for `127.0.1.1` from `/etc/hosts` on both master and slave nodes.